# A word meaning either arrow or bolt

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a word which could mean arrow or crossbow-bolt (but not other missiles like stones, darts or javelins or whatever).

More specifically I'm trying to use it as a description for what happens when you're hit with 'one of those'. I was considering 'shaft' or 'barb' but those are just specific parts of the thing itself.

Comment: bolt of lightning or bolt of nuts and bolts?

Comment: Bolt of crossbow. Let me updated the question

Comment: Since a *bolt* is a type of arrow, you would just use *arrow.*

Comment: *Projectile* is the most general term.

Comment: @ChrisSunami, that would be a good answer.

Comment: @ScotM I made it into one.  The more I think about it, there can't really be any other answer --it's like asking for a word that means "animal or dog."

Comment: _arrow-like projectiles_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that a bolt is a type of arrow, there really can't be any other answer than **arrow.**

Comment: +1, but it's amazing how many times I have said, "There is no word for that," only to be embarrassed when someone presented a word for it :-)

Comment: I actually never considered bolts to be subelements of arrows (which is why I thought I was missing an obvious word). Still, might work for my own needs.

Answer (score 1):

[Projectile](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/projectile?searchDictCode=all) includes both *arrow* and *bolt* (in addition to other things that can be thrown from various weapons and tools):

> 1.1 An object propelled through the air, especially one thrown as a weapon:

Comment: I want to restrict the term to arrows or bolts, and not other missiles.

Comment: Then *arrow* is the word, unless we find a better one.

Comment: The thing about these projectiles is that they're pointed. I.e, they're useless if they tumble. So they hafta be either balanced (like a pub dart), or guided by fletchings of some sort (like an arrow), or both, in order to make sure that the pointed business end arrives at its destination first and fast. So I'd say "pointed projectile" as a general term.